# Http Response Headers and URLRewrite headers only applying to Https calls not Http

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, url-rewriting, response-headers

Hi so I have been adding the needed headers to my site in IIS specifying them in 'Http Response Headers' like so...

[image]

I am also setting an Outbound Rule using UrlRewrite to remove Server details...

[image]

When I run a header check calling the Https address for my site I get the correct Headers as seen here...

[image]

Http is disabled on my site so if you try to call one of the addresses using Http it will auto divert to using Https. However I still ran a header check on Http address for the site and strangely done of the Header Responses or Rewrites I made take effect. See below

[image]

Does anyone know how I can ensure that my Headers for Http are the same as Https?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try below another way to remove X-Powered-By and iis version header:

To remove X-Powered-By:

1. Open iis manager, select site for which you would like to remove the header.
2. Select "HTTP Response Headers" feature from the middle pane
3. Select the "X-Powered-By" HTTP Header and select "Remove"

To removeServerHeader:

1. Open iis manager, select the site for which you would like to remove the header.
2. Double click "Configuration Editor"
3. select "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering" section
4. Set removeServerHeader to True -> click apply

[image]